# Restful API call is passing in a null object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller, model

I have an MVC application that calls APIs that update or returns data to the users screen. When I call the API it is passing in a null object. I have debugged the code and the data is fine and fits the model before the API is called so I cant seem to find why it is null. All other API calls work fine, this is the only one that I'm passing an object through though.

I have used Postman to call the API and it works perfectly, i have also used fiddler to find what the json is that is being sent to the API when called from the application, and its got the same settings and json that i used with postman. I have tried adding [FromBody] into the API controller and also changed the parameter to be JObject to see if I could get anything through. Any one any ideas?

Below is what is being sent to the API when i used postman and the application, its the same for both:

```
POST http://localhost/HealthStatusAPI/api/ConfigUpdate HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

{"MsgConfigUpdate":[{"Address":"http://EndpointURL1/EndpointService1.svc","Active":true}]}
```

Model:

```
public class ConfigUpdateList
{
    public List<ConfigUpdate> MsgConfigUpdate { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigUpdate
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

API Controller Method:

```
public class ConfigUpdateController : ApiController
{
    private IMonitorActions monitorActions;

    public ConfigUpdateController(IMonitorActions monitorActions)
    {
        this.monitorActions = monitorActions;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult PostConfigUpdateList(ConfigUpdateList MsgConfigUpdate)
    {     
        bool result = MonitorActions.ConfigUpdate(MsgConfigUpdate);

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

MVC Application Call:

```
public async Task<ConfigUpdateList> PostConfigUpdateList(ConfigUpdateList MsgConfigUpdate)
{
    using (var client = SetUpHttpClient())
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ConfigUpdate", MsgConfigUpdate);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }                           
    }
}
```

SetUpHTTPClient Method:

```
private HttpClient SetUpHttpClient()
    {            
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string RootAddress = _config["SecureAppSettings:ApiRootAddress"];
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0); //10 seconds
        client.Timeout = timeout;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RootAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));            
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicCredentials(sUserName, sPassword);

        return client;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the API method signature like:

From:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostConfigUpdateList(ConfigUpdateList MsgConfigUpdate)
```

To:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostConfigUpdateList([FromBody]ConfigUpdateList MsgConfigUpdate)
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this already and it didnt work! Still passed a null object in

Comment: Your `MsgConfigUpdate` has any value when it reaches the controller from the view?

Comment: Yea it has all the values that were selected from the checkbox in the view. The object has all the values in it right up to the point were it does the API call, then when i debug the API call its NULL